# Erro discord.js v14 (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS'))

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**"const's"**

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, Permissions } = require("discord.js"); 
const GuildSettings = require("../models/GuildSettings");
```

**Codding**

```
if(!interaction.member.permissions.has([Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR]))
{
interaction.reply("Você não possui permissão para executar este comando");
return;   
}
```

**Erro console**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
```

*Note: I appreciate if you can help me. In itself is a configuration system that saves everything in a variable. But it's not ready yet, but even this part was supposed to be at least working. As much as it's still not saving directly to a variable (which I need to test this out).*

Comment: Can you show us the full file in the question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Djsv14 you have to change your code a little bit

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionsBitField } = require("discord.js"); 
const GuildSettings = require("../models/GuildSettings");

if(!interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator))
{
interaction.reply("Você não possui permissão para executar este comando");
return;   
}
```

Comment: Source : Djs Official Guide | I have also tested myself